# React: Appbar material-ui nao é mostrada

Tags: javascript, react, material-design

Olá, Instalei o material-ui no react para fazer testes, mas a AppBar nao mostra na tela. Criei um componente Appbar que usa a AppBar do material-ui, depois usei ele na classe App, e mesmo assim nao funcionou.

Códigos:

Appbar.js:

```
        import React from "react"
    import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, List, ListItem, ListItemText } from "material-ui"

    class Appbar extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <AppBar color="primary" position="static">
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
                                InstaPets
                            </Typography>
                            <List component="nav">
                                <ListItem component="div">
                                    <ListItemText>
                                        <a href="facebook.com">Feed</a>
                                    </ListItemText>

                                    <ListItemText>

                                        <a href="facebook.com">Post</a>
                                    </ListItemText>

                                    <ListItemText>
                                        <a href="facebook.com">Login/Register</a>
                                    </ListItemText>

                                </ListItem>
                            </List>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default Appbar;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Appbar from "./components/Appbar"
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Appbar/>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Procure inspecionar o código pra descobrir se o componente está sendo renderizado ou não.

Sugestões:

1. Remova aquela "div fantasma" que precede o `<AppBar>` e deixe o `<AppBar>` como raiz.
2. Adicione uma `className` pra div que precede o `<AppBar>` e estilize em um .css externo (Não esqueça de importá-lo).

Se o `<AppBar>` possui estilos default / deve aparecer sem mexer em estilo nenhum, certifique-se de que não se esqueceu de importar algum estilo do material-ui.